# How can I publish my web api in core 2.1 (System Files)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to publish my web api in .net core 2.1 with system files ...but when I publish it, in my computer I only see .dll , .json , but not others files , so I don’t know how to do that publish and put all the files in my IIS 
I need an special configuration in my web api ? Or how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x

https://andrewlock.net/exploring-program-and-startup-in-asp-net-core-2-preview1-2/

https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/

Running `dotnet publish` will generate the contents which you put in a directory pointed out in your IIS application pool (you specify the directory during the server application pool's set up - check the links)

Yes, in some way you need a special configuration file - `web.config`

Comment: I already wrote in the cmd dotnet publish, and in my folde I see the files...but when I open the api in my browser , I see the error: Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Comment: Does the error contain the details?Do you have the web.config file defined? Do you have files with names like appsettings.*.json inside your project's directory?

Comment: You can also try to search for the logs from the IIS using [event viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51912729/4880379)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/sdk)

Check: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Install -> dotnet-hosting-2.1.3-win.exe
Commands:

-> net stop was y

-> net start w3svc

Restart IIS

AppPool -> NoManagedCode - Integrated

After is just like publishing a normal asp.net project in IIS.

Comment: I already installed the SDK...next I published my web api in a folder, but when I try to test it, I have this error Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error
and in my Program.cs
        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .Build();

Comment: @365lol Have you [installed the .net core hosting bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle)?

Comment: Updated my answer. Sorry about the delay