# IIS Error The error occurred while starting the application

Tags: .net, iis, .net-core, nopcommerce

I have been using nopCommerce 4.1 on IIS 10. We are facing an issue where the application stop working with an error...

The error occurred while starting the application.

Here is the screenshot for the same: http://prntscr.com/ngk6ep

When we do manual pool recycle it start working however, we have no clue what happens and why its stopped working after certain internal.

What could be wrong? Any clue?

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could try to enable the fail request tracing to get the original exception. According to the  original exception, we could know why and how to solve this issue. More details about how to enable the IIS FRT, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).

Answer (score 2):

Open your web config and set stdoutLogEnabled = "True" then you will find real exception in "log" folder of your root directory or "logs\stdout" directory

Comment: The whole tag is: `<aspNetCore ... stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />`. And note that you also must create this folder and give IIS_IUSRS permission to modify (create files) that folder. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536073/where-do-logs-go-when-running-asp-net-core-on-iis-7-5