# HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am a junior software developer and to be brief, I recently built an API by creating an `ASP.NET Web Application` and choosing `Web API`. Added to that was the `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`. What it did? All that was done by that API was retrieving data from an `Amazon RDS`. Everything worked great, this is an example output

```
[
    {
      "demo_id": "id_value",
      "demo_name": "data 1",
      "demo_specificity": "Total",
      "demo_period": "'May'",
      "demo_value": 10
    },
    {
      "demo_id": "id_value",
      "demo_name": "data 2",
      "demo_specificity": "Total",
      "demo_period": "'May'",
      "demo_value": 544
    }
]
```

Later I was asked to convert it as a serverless app with `AWS Lambda` and `AWS API Gateway`.
I followed these instructions https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/aspnet-core-aws-lambda-serverless-application/.
I installed the AWS toolkit on `Visual Studio` created an `AWS serverless app` and into the solution I added my `API project` which `I referenced in my AWS serverless app`. This is the project structure

[image]

In my API (`ObservatoireAPI`) this was my `Controller`:

```
using ObservatoireAPI.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ObservatoireAPI.Controllers
{
    public class ObservatoireController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<SLM_RAW_INDICATORS> GetSLM_RAW_INDICATORS()
        {
            using(gpaEntities entities = new gpaEntities())
            {
                return entities.SLM_RAW_INDICATORS.ToList();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

And in my `ObservatoireAWS` (AWS Serverless APP) Controller I just called that function this way:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ObservatoireAPI.Controllers;

namespace ObservatoireAWS.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ObservatoireAWSController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            ObservatoireController api = new ObservatoireController();
            var apiResult = api.GetSLM_RAW_INDICATORS();

            return Ok(apiResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Honestly I'm sure I did everything great, but on launching the app (locally first), I get `HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure`. I tried googling and people were recommending switching between `In Process` and `Out Process`. I tried the Out Process but it crashed so i left it back the way it was.Not willing to alter configs I didn't understand I preferred opening an issue.

Here are two solution that i tried to implement but that didn't work for me:

1. [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6111)
2. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939860/how-to-fix-error-ancm-in-process-handler-load-failure)

Once more thanks.

This is my `dotnet --info`

```
Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.301\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.5
  Commit:  65cd789777

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture the original working request and compare with non working request.  Usually the c# headers in first request are not correct.  c# default headers are different from other tools and usually need to be modified so they look like the working applicaiton.

Comment: when I get this it is usually some missing configuration in the config json. I would suggest putting a try catch around the entry point(Program.cs) which gives more details if its what I think it is