# Visual Studio build fail but no error shown

Tags: visual-studio

There are several similar questions but no one of them actually works for me.

I wanted to make a .Net Core application (API) but as I said the build fails (even with the default application). If I try to continue, IIS shows "Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure".
Tried everything, from restarting VS to deleting and reinstalling it but it does not work. It instead works on a virtual machine but have no idea what's the difference. What might I do?
*Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.8.3*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error "ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939860/how-to-fix-error-ancm-in-process-handler-load-failure)

Comment: [Windows error register]
Application: MSBuild.exe
framework version: v4.0.30319
Description: process terminated due to an unhandled exception
Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException
   in System.SpanHelpers.IndexOf(Char ByRef, Char, Int32)
   in System.MemoryExtensions.IndexOf[[System.Char, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.ReadOnlySpan`1<Char>, Char) ... and many other lines

Comment: @ken-y-n yes I saw that but nope, it does not work

Answer (score 2):

I've the same error but in an ASPNET u need see the errors in the build/debugging output

[I've an error but that don't show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0eNx.png)

You need to find the error within the logs

[My error was an update Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brScy.png)

////
EDIT:
[Try this: Select Entire Solution and Build Only to show the Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d03Gx.png)

Comment: Hi, in a previous comment I wrote down what the error is. Could you look at it?