# Cannot debug with Visual studio 2019 -HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug my own application, but when I launch it with the VS2019, he shows me this message:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure.

At the beginning I had found on the internet that it is necessary to modify in the web.config  the hostingModel from "InProcess" to "OutProcess" but I could no longer launch the application.

After that, I tried to run the application with dotnet run with command line,the **ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure is gone** and in the same time i runned the application from VS2019,the error is gone also.

My application work now in Localhost with two Different Ports.

My problem now is When i made some change in my code i have to repeat this procedure to access debug :

- shutdown application from command line (if its already up)
- rebuild app with command line or IDE
- execute dotnet run with command line
- launch it with debugger of IDE

**if anyone encountered such a problem, how did they solve it**

Comment: I found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939860/how-to-fix-error-ancm-in-process-handler-load-failure), you can try to modify `modules` to `AspNetCoreModule` in web.config file

Answer (score 0):

By any chance, did your project name end with the characters "**dotnet**", like "myapp**dotnet**.csproj"? I discovered that when trying to run any project that ends in those characters, IIS Express throws this exact error.

Unfortunately, I have no idea where this would be documented--if it is.