# Extend IIS logs in .Net Core 2.2 Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, iis-logs

I'm moving stuff from my ASP.Net MVC application (.Net Framework 4.7) to a new .Net Core 2.2 API.

In my old MVC application I added some specific POST properties to the IIS logs via [HttpResponseBase.AppendToLog()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.appendtolog). I can't find a similar method in .Net Core.

My question: how can I add properties that are in the HttpPost to the IIS logs in a .Net Core Api? This is how the logs look like:

```
2019-06-26 19:34:07 website-ip-address POST /some-endpoint [data-to-log-ended-here] 443 username ip-address etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer to your question, but I found two posts that may relate to what you are asking

- [How to log http POST data to IIS log in asp.net core](https://forums.asp.net/t/2110895.aspx?How%20to%20log%20http%20POST%20data%20to%20IIS%20log%20in%20asp%20net%20core)
- [Where do logs go when running ASP.NET Core on IIS 7.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536073/where-do-logs-go-when-running-asp-net-core-on-iis-7-5)

Generally, in an Asp.net Core app it's more common to use its [logging API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to work with a powerful 3rd party logging libraries like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) to easily log to a number of [different sources](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks) you can choose from. Though IIS is not one of them, I'd recommend take a look at Application Insights which is very popular for doing logging in Asp.net Core applications.  Hope this helps somewhat!

Comment: thanks! I know the logging API. For this small project it's easier to have 1 log and the IIS logs were a perfect place. I'll have a look at the other case and let you know how it works out!