# Asp.Net core 3.1 web application terminates unexpectedly without any exception while running

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a .net core 3.1 web application, specifically it is an identity server 4 app which i use to get token for other client apps. Now consider the app was running correctly and also producing tokens for clients but suddenly it terminated without any exception and this is happening many times.

Comment: Edit your web.config to log to stdout: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40536073/66207

Answer (score 0):

Identity server 4 events logging is available in output window while running identity server. Please check events log in output window and try to see what is going on. Moreover you can share log.

Comment: can you tell me please how to check events log in output window. As i am unable to see anything with name event in output window

Comment: when identity server 4 get request all processing logged into output window of visual studio. press ctrl+Alt+O to open output window. i can share image with you but due to short reputation not able to share image. plz vote it if it helps you

Comment: i have opened output window but i cant'see any use full information there

Comment: I can see many more lines like these 'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'F:\Insignia Projects\Colaraz_Revamp\src\Services\Identity\Identity.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'F:\Insignia Projects\Colaraz_Revamp\src\Services\Identity\Identity.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Comment: info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
testIDP>       User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\kumar144\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
testIDP> Hosting environment: Development
testIDP> Content root path: xxxxxx\testIDP
testIDP> Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:19803
testIDP> Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
testIDP> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]

Comment: testIDP>       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:61777/  
testIDP> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
testIDP>       Request starting HTTP/1.1 DEBUG http://localhost:61777/  0
testIDP>       Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:61777/connect/token application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8 119
testIDP> info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
testIDP>       Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
testIDP> info: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]

Comment: User authentication failed: Incorrect Login or Password
testIDP> info: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
testIDP>       {
testIDP> "ClientId": "xxx",
testIDP>  "ClientName": "xx",
testIDP> "GrantType": "password",
testIDP> "Scopes": "offline_access teAPI",
testIDP>  "UserName": "xxx",
testIDP>   "Raw": {
testIDP>      "username": "xxxxx",
testIDP>           "password": "***REDACTED***",
testIDP>           "grant_type": "password",
testIDP>           "client_id": "xxxxxxx",
testIDP>           "client_secret": "***REDACTED***"
testIDP>         }
testIDP>       }

Comment: you will log like above comments and you can see all are info log and when you will get error then error will be marked

Comment: ok so you are taking about logs. I am logging all the logs into log file but when application terminates and i check logs i see that there is no err logged into logs file. And also if there any exception occurs visual studio shows the exception but not in my case, i think it is not any exception which causes the application to terminate it is some other problem which i don't know

Comment: is your problem encountered in production or development environment(visual studio)?

Comment: both in production and in development environment. In production i face the problem server has been shutdown or service is unavailable several time and in development(visual studio) i see that application terminates without any exception